# I just transfered domain name and now within my .htaccess file I have two codes which seem the same should one be deleted?

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} lagiraudiere\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.lagiraudiere.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This cannot be answered without information on the application setup.

Comment: Why have you posted these two rules separately? Do you have other directives in the file (between these two rules)? Are these directives in the order you've stated? Are you hosting multiple domains? These two rules do not quite do the same thing (and the first rule looks incomplete). But only one rule will be doing anything. What exactly are you wanting to do? HTTP to HTTPS _and_ non-www to www canonical redirection? What does this have to do with having transferred your domain name?